# How to restore the computer's username in Terminal?

Tags: macos, terminal

I would like to restore the previous name (default) in my terminal. How can I do that?

I changed to $ sign only by applying this code:

```
echo "export PS1='$ '" >> ~/.bash_profile
. ~/.bash_profile
```

but couldn't manage to restore it.

Comment: When you say name, are you talking about showing the username in the prompt or title of the terminal window?   Have you tried running bash with the --noprofile flag set?  If you could show an example of what you are trying to do that would be great.

Answer (score 1):

Simply enter

```
nano ~/.bash_profile
```

then go to the line

```
export PS1='$ '
```

and delete that line. Then save the file and exit nano. After then execute

```
. ~/.bash_profile
```

That will be load the settings from this file.

Answer (score 0):

Simply remove the line you appended to your ~/.bash_profile and restart your shell.